# hide() not working completely in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

I am developing a jquery mobile app and need to hide certain input fields if a certain action is taken. I use

`$("#idname").hide()`

and it works but not completely, there is a line were the field once was, it seems like the field is not hidden but just made very small. I have tried using css,

`$("#idname").css("display", "none")`

but that gives the same results. does anyone have a solution to this problem.

Comment: can you post detailed code?

Comment: "input fields" as in plural? id should be unique

Comment: Please fiddle your code so that we can see what is happening.

Comment: i have created a fiddle that shows my issue, thank you again for the assistance. http://jsfiddle.net/gmakungo/Ka9X4/

Answer (score 2):

Check once if there are two ids with same name in a page or not. A page must have only one id with identiacal name. Rather than id, you can try this with use of class attribute.

Comment: the ids are different and I have tried to use the the class attribute but that does not work either

Comment: have you imported jquery.min.js?

Comment: yes i have, the problem is that there is a trace of the hidden field in the form of a line, that line is what i want to get rid of.  If the field element is of type hidden then there is no trace of it, but if one hide the field dynamically (like when a button is clicked) then you can see that the is a line where the hidden field was, its as though the field is not hidden, its just minimized, I would like to know how to get rid of that line, thanks for your help